# I can't run Asymptote with Mac OS X Lion

Tags: installing, mac, asymptote

Should I wait for MacTeX 2012? Can I use TeXShop to run asymptote? I am not good with terminal.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 6):

TeXShop comes with an 'engine' for Asymptote, so it's easy to run it from TeXShop.  To install the engine, go to `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/` (on Lion, this folder is hidden, so you need to go to the Go menu item in the Finder and enter the path directly) and move the `Asymptote.engine` file from the `Inactive/Asymptote` folder to the `Engines` folder.  There's also a sample `.tex` file in that folder that you can look at.

Restart TeXShop, and the new engine should appear in the pulldown menu beside the Typeset button in the document window.  When you want to run Asymptote, choose that Engine from the pulldown menu and the hit the Typeset button.

Comment: I tried that and was able to process the `sample.tex` file with the Asymptote engien. However, the graphics for the cube, the large Euler's formula display, and the horizontal dimensional arrows all seemed out of place, overwriting the text "One can also scale the figure to the full line width:".

Comment: How does one get the GUI version, `xasy`, to run under OS X? I've never been able to get the library dependencies satisfied.

Comment: @murray The sample file compiles fine for me except that the coordinate of the label of the cube is slightly off (it should be `(1,1,0.5)` instead of `(0,1,0.5)`.  But to get the cube displayed correctly on the page you have to use the `[inline]` option for the package.  As for the GUI version, I have no idea, as I don't actually use Asymptote.

Comment: In `sample.tex`, when I change the cube's label coordinates from `(0,1,0.5)` to `(1,1,0.5)` then the cube and its label both disappear entirely from the output.