# Integrating Asymptote into TeXShop

Tags: texshop, asymptote

I'm trying to integrate Asymptote into my TeXShop, which I have been unsuccessful in so far.
I've tried the instructions given in the document [Integrating Asymptote and TeXShop for Mac OS X](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/TeXShopAndAsymptote.pdf),
but once I get to the `cd asymptote-x.xx` part, my terminal says

```
-bash: cd: asymptote-2.35: No such file or directory
```

From here I'm kind of stuck.
I'm kind of a noob at computers, and I don't really know what .tgz, or .tar, or like the `usr` folder is (created after I enter the `tar -xf asymptote-x.xx.src.tar` command into terminal).

Can anyone help me to install Asymptote and integrate it into TeXShop?

Some stuff about computer and programs:

- TeXShop: Version 3.51
- OS: OSX 10.9.5, Mavericks (I think)
- Asymptote Version: `2.35.i386.tgz` is the version I'm trying to install I believe.

Comment: If you install MacTeX it will include Asymptote. Anything else is overly complicated.

Comment: The instructions in the document you link to are overly complicated. I suggest the following instead. First, install MacTeX--full installation--if you haven't already. Then, follow the much simpler instructions at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62350/484.

Answer (score 1):

TeXShop has an asymtotemk engine that will automatically deal with asymptote. By default it's inactive. Please look at the Help->TeXShop Tips and Tricks document for some information on how to activate that engine (as well as others) and how to have TeXShop automatically use that engine

Comment: For anyone else struggling to get this solution to work, note that it failed for me until I removed all spaces from my LaTeX document filename, at which point it began working.  (By "fail" I mean silently not including the asymptote figure(s) in the typeset PDF document.)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to setup asymptote, Latex and TexEditor for AOPS and came across the issue with Mac installs. After trying couple of other options, I think TexShop is the easiest and simple method to install. In step 2 of http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/TeXShopAndAsymptote.pdf, once you finish the second statement (tar -xf asymptote-x.xxx.src.tar), you can proceed to step 3. I spent a ton of time rebuilding with errors and thats not required at all.

Comment: While the link you posted is certainly useful, posting links as an answer is discouraged on this site.  Perhaps you could summarize the information found at this link and present them in a short example.

Comment: TexShop has an Asymptote engine in fact.